# How to access resource file's value in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

In the `xml` I am able to access resource file's value by providing the corresponding key.
First I have added the namespace as following

```
xmlns:res="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3.Properties"
```

And then bind the Text using following way

```
Text="{x:Static res:Resources.city}"
```

But in my same application I have to use it in code behind. What should I do it to access my resource file?

When I count the key of my resource file I found it `0` that does not make any sense as I have many keys in my resource file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be as simple as:

```
var cityName = Properties.Resources.city;
```

Comment: Any idea how to make a [binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to that form code behind? #[Create binding to string in Resources.resx from code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35755990/2596334)

Answer (score 0):

If the resource file is local to the `UserControl` / `Window` then try this ...

in the code behind at in the usings at the top ...

`using Resx = NameSpace.Resources` ... call it what you like here.

Wut `NameSpace`? - Look for it in the `.Designer.cs` resource file, the namespace that code is in.

then in the code behind ...

`string actualText = Resx.Class.propertyNameOfResource`

Wut `Class` ?  - this one you're in right now (pun intended)
Wut `propertyNameOfResource` - that's the Resource Key. VS Intellisense should work there.

Also handy is https://github.com/mrlacey/StringResourceVisualizer which shows you the actual strings in Visual Studio

But you just broke any bindings you previously had if you assign it to a UI Control's content.