# Create binding to string in Resources.resx from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, code-behind, resx

I started by making a label in XAML with its content bound to a string in my resources file. I've implemented localization and confirm that when I change languages, the label's content updates accordingly.

Now I need to do the same from code behind.

Here is a taste of the XAML:

```XAML
<Grid Background="#FF313131">
  <ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel x:Name="GeneralTab_StackPanel">

      <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{Binding AxisDataColorCode}" Margin="2,2,2,0">
        <Label x:Name="lbl_General_MachineType" Content="{Binding GUI_MachineType, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" FontSize="20" />
        <Label x:Name="lbl_General_MachineTypeResult" Content="{Binding MachineBaseType}" FontSize="20" />
      </WrapPanel>

      <WrapPanel....
```

Attempting to recreate this in code-behind I have the following:

```C#
Binding BgColorBinding = new Binding("AxisDataColorCode");

// Something needs to change here. I've tried a bunch of things already with no luck.
Binding GUI_MachineTypeBinding = new Binding("GUI_MachineType");
GUI_MachineTypeBinding.Source = Properties.Resources.GUI_MachineType;

Binding MachineBaseTypeBinding = new Binding("MachineBaseType");


Label Label_MachineType = new Label();
Label_MachineType.Name = "lbl_General_MachineType";
Label_MachineType.FontSize = 20;

// This does not work at all. Help!
Label_MachineType.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, GUI_MachineTypeBinding);

// this works! but it's not a binding and doesn't update...
// Label_MachineType.Content = Properties.Resources.GUI_MachineType;

Label Label_MachineTypeResult = new Label();
Label_MachineTypeResult.Name = "lbl_General_MachineTypeResult";
Label_MachineTypeResult.FontSize = 20;
Label_MachineTypeResult.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, MachineBaseTypeBinding);

WrapPanel MachineTypeWrapPanel = new WrapPanel();
MachineTypeWrapPanel.Name = "MachineTypeWrapPanel";
MachineTypeWrapPanel.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
MachineTypeWrapPanel.Margin = new Thickness(2, 2, 2, 0);
MachineTypeWrapPanel.SetBinding(WrapPanel.BackgroundProperty, BgColorBinding);
MachineTypeWrapPanel.Children.Add(Label_MachineType);
MachineTypeWrapPanel.Children.Add(Label_MachineTypeResult);
```

My other bindings work fine, because I've just tied them to properties in code behind that implement property changed notification.

Trying to bind to any of the keys in my resources however, gives me nothing. The label's content is simply blank, and there are no errors in my debug output window.

I can't find any examples of anyone binding to their *Properties.Resources.Whatever* from code behind anywhere.

---

**The solution:**

*Thanks Henka!*

```
Binding GUI_MachineTypeBinding = new Binding("GUI_MachineType");
GUI_MachineTypeBinding.Source = Application.Current.FindResource("Resources");
....
Label_MachineType.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, GUI_MachineTypeBinding);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the Binding from code behind the UI will not be notified you should create your custom extension and save a `WeakReference` to the `DependencyProperty` and update the value when the culture changed, i propose an other solution to use, have a look at this article.[Advanced WPF Localization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249369/Advanced-WPF-Localization)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this. My localization implementation is very similar to the one you linked to. I am updating properties and dependency properties upon culture change via `ResourceProvider_DataChanged` event. Creating an intermediate binding for keys in the resource dictionary does not seem like it should be necessary however.

Comment: try to set the binding source to Properties.Resources not to the property itself

Comment: Doesn't work. "...resources is a type, which is not valid in the given context". Also after looking at code from that solution you linked, I am **sure** it would have the same issue. Nothing in the demo is created procedurally, they all bind to static resources in XAML.

Comment: Try to define the StaticResource `Resources` in your app resources, and the Binding source set to Application.Current.FindResource()

Comment: You are a genius! It worked! I have updated my answer with the solution.